How many integers within a range can be formed from given digits, that satisfy divisibility by a certain number, and contain a specified substring?
How many  $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $ 104050607080 \leq x \leq 908070605040$ , can be formed using the digits of $106506506503$, such that $x$ is divisible by $20$ and contains the string "$036$" as a substring?
I am reposting this exercise (already answered here) because I wonder if there is a less-time consuming approach. My professor told me that a solution by complement, for this exercise, is too much time-consuming and further it would requires to analyse too many cases. He suggested to count directly the substrings that satisfy those conditions but honestly I have no clue how to do this.
How can exercise be solved more quickly?
Edit:

Please note that substring can only appear once.
Please note that the leftmost digit of any positive integer is not permitted to equal 0.
Please also note that I am not allowed to use computational tools otherwise I would have solved this exercise in C++ or Java.

Solution Outline (as my professor requested)

Available Digits:

We can only use the digits of the number ( 106506506503 ). The digits are: ( 1, 0, 6, 5, 0, 6, 5, 0, 6, 5, 3 ).
Thus, we have the digit frequencies:

Three ( 0 )'s
Three ( 6 )'s
Three ( 5 )'s
One ( 1 )
One ( 3 )




Divisibility by 20:

For ( x ) to be divisible by 20, the number must end in "00", as divisibility by 20 implies the number is divisible by both 5 and 4. This imposes the following restrictions:

The last two digits must be "00".
Therefore, at least two ( 0 )'s must be used at the end of ( x ).




Contains Substring "036":

The number ( x ) must also contain the string "036" somewhere in its digits. This introduces another restriction:

We must reserve the digits "036" somewhere within the number ( x ).




Total Number of Digits:

The total length of ( x ) can be at most 12 digits because the number ( 106506506503 ) consists of 12 digits.
Since two digits are used for the "00" at the end and three digits are reserved for "036", we are left with ( 12 - 5 = 7 ) digits to fill with the remaining available digits.


Combinatorial Setup:

We now calculate how many valid combinations of digits can be formed, given the constraints.
The process involves the following combinatorial choices:

We first place the "036" somewhere in the number ( x ), excluding the last two positions (which are occupied by "00").
Then, we fill in the remaining ( 7 ) positions using the available digits ( {1, 6, 5, 5, 6, 5, 6} ).




Calculating the Number of Valid Combinations:

Using binomial coefficients, we calculate the number of ways to arrange the remaining digits.


Subtraction of Invalid Cases:

The solution subtracts certain invalid cases where either the substring "036" does not appear, or the number is not divisible by 20.
The total valid cases ( A ) are computed and invalid cases ( B ) are subtracted from it, yielding the final result ( A - B ).



Conclusion
By following this process, we compute the number of valid integers ( x ) that meet the given conditions. The approach combines the constraints of divisibility by 20, the inclusion of the substring "036", and the combinatorics of arranging the digits of ( 106506506503 ).
Can someone help me now in applying this process?

I don't see this as a Stars and Bars problem.  Perhaps I am overlooking something.  Anyway, in general, the Inclusion-Exclusion approach is to be preferred over the direct approach, because the Inclusion-Exclusion approach is very straightforward, and less likely to result in an analytical error.  Of course, the direct approach is do-able.  You can ignore the upper bound, and the string can not start with either 100... or 103...  ...see next comment

The string must end in either 00 or 60, and must contain 0360 somewhere.  If the direct approach is used, then (absent any elegant approach that I am overlooking) the problem becomes a manual exercise in careful counting.

@user2661923 sorry, you're right, I edited the original post. No elegant approach as far as I know. Would you mind giving me an example on the exact steps of careful counting for the given exercise?

@user2661923: I like your approach, but seen the rather bizarre choice of boundaries for this question, I would rather describe it as an exercise in programming than manual counting :-)

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

@Dominique sadly we are not allowed to solve this programmatically.

@user2661923 I've updated my question, please check it out!

It appears the question changes midstream in the OP. Wait, the number must not only be in the prescribed range and be divisible by $20$ and use $036$ as a substring, but [reading right below "solution outline/available digits"] we cannot use the digits $2,4,7,8,9$? Please clarify. [I had to vote "Needs details/clarity"]

@Mike How exactly does my question change? Yes, correct, we can't use those digits because they are not in the set of available digits.

I apologize I reread the top paragraph

It seems to me that regardless of whether Inclusion-Exclusion or the direct approach is used, the solution will require very tedious examination of various cases.  I don't see any elegant approach.

@user2661923 it's much faster though this way, it counts strings that satisfy the divisibility and subtract from them the violation of the lower bound.
